# Will the sftp server hung up when we continuously poll it using spring inbound-channel adaptor

Tags: spring-integration

I am using spring integation poller to download files from an sftp server

```
<int-sftp:inbound-channel-adapter channel="myFileDownloadChannel"
                                      session-factory="mySftpSessionFactory"
                                      remote-directory="#{remote}"
                                      filter = "modifiedFileListFilter"
                                      local-directory="#{local}"
                                      auto-create-local-directory="true">
<integration:poller cron="10 * * * * *" default="true"/>
</int-sftp:inbound-channel-adapter>

 <integration:service-activator input-channel="myFileDownloadChannel"
                                ref="errorTransformer" 
                                output-channel="endChannel"/>
```

I am running this code in 6 servers.

1. Will it hung up the sftp server if the 6 servers are polling it every 10 min?.
2. Does it make new connections each time the poller is triggered?.

Please advice.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

1. It depends on the server, but it's probably not a big deal; doesn't sound like high volume to me.
2. You can wrap the session factory in a `CachingSessionFactory` to keep the session open, but many servers are configured to drop idle connections anyway.

Comment: I found out that we need to specify  "cache-sessions = false"
Setting that to FALSE (it's TRUE by default) will cause it to close sessions per use. Will this work?

Answer (score 0):

Add a boolean variable `"cache-sessions = false"` to `<int-sftp:inbound-channel-adapter`

it's **TRUE** by default. and will keep the `connections open.`

set it as **FALSE**, it will `close sessions per use`.

Comment: Why?  A bit of rationale is very helpful to future visitors.